# Checking for character '\' from an input text

Tags: javascript

Basically i was trying to restrict special characters from input.

```
var iChars = "[!@#$%^&*()+=\\-\\[\\]\\\';,./{}|\":<>?\\n]{1}";
if(((document.all.tranRmks.value).search(iChars)) != -1){
     alert("Speacial characters not allowed in Notes");
     return false;
}
```

But now i need to check for character `'\'` .

```
if(((document.all.tranRmks.value).indexOf("\"))>=0){
    alert("\ not allowed");
    return false;
}
```

But the above code is not working for me..Please let me know any other way to check `\`.

Comment: The \ escapes the next quote. Use 2 \.

Answer (score 1):

as @Vohuman has said, the backslash escapes the next character which here is the closing `literal(")`. use `\\` instead.

```
if(((document.all.tranRmks.value).indexOf("\\"))>=0){
    alert("\\ not allowed");
    return false;
}
```

**OR**

you could use the includes() functions which checks for existence of the string given.

```
 if((document.all.tranRmks.value).includes("\\")){
        alert("\\ not allowed");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: But i need to check for single back slash..will the above code works??

Comment: Yes, internally it is a single backslash, The above code perfectly works. I've tested it.